# Windows 8 desktop DirectX-11 development equivalent of ReadDataAsync()?

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx

I'm trying to access the ReadDataAsync() function to get a pointer to the compiled shader byte data to pass to CreateVertexShader(). I am trying to do this on windows 8 desktop in directx 11.

This function exists in the windows 8 metro development side of things in the header file DirectXHelper.h. However, it is my understanding that DirectXHelper.h does not exist on windows 8 desktop development (written in standard c++).

I am trying to duplicate page 21 of http://d3dcoder.net/Data/Resources/d3d11Metro.pdf
in windows 8 desktop, and not windows 8 metro.

Does anybody know of how I could accomplish this? Or an equivalent of the function ReadDataAsync()?

Comment: All metro APIs are available and supported on the desktop.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Would those applications that use the metro APIs still be able to run on a Windows 7 environment? If not, then why bother writing a desktop application at all?

Comment: @mikeschuld No, the WinRT APIs are not backwards-compatible. For desktop users?

Comment: No, I was wondering for people writing the app in a Win8 environment (where these nice async helpers are readily available) but who want Win7 people to be able to run it as well.

Comment: Are you using vs 2012? If so, just compile it using fxc and open the file with c/c++ to get the characters of the compiled shader (the .cso file). You can pass that into the CreateXXXShader() function with the appropriate file size. If you need more details let me know.